# what is the better approach in sharing session of asp classic and asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, cookies

I have an asp classic and asp.net application. I want to share the session from asp classic to asp.net back and forth. I made a solution to share the session by iterating the session names and put it in the hidden objects. This works fine , but I don't know if it is a better approach to share the session. iread some articles some of them using xml and pass it through form posting, some using cookies, and the other are using database.From this approach, what is the best to impleemnt with, or is there any other best solution?

Comment: The best solution would depend on your parameters or definition for "best".  What is your main concern?  Performance?  Maintenance of the code?  Ease of implementation?  Also, if you could elaborate on your usage of sessions, it might make it easier to recommend different approaches.  What kind of things are your storing in session?

Comment: @Daniel-my main concern here is about the easy implementation, security, performance and of course maintenance of code. 
I need to share the session because the other application needs the value as a parameter or for a variety of settings and conditons. From this, when going back to the previous application, the value should remain as is.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your description of what you've already done is not very clear:

> I made a solution to share the session by iterating the session names and put it in the hidden objects.

So, I'm going to go back one step and approach it from there.  Before that, however, I should say that I don't think integrating two systems on this level is a good idea at all; you are trying to make two systems work together by replacing some of the piping that they run on, in such a way that they don't really notice.  This might open you up for errors later on, when something changes and the relevant change is not made in the other system.  I also would advise against the heavy use of sessions in general, although many ASP systems did abuse it.

Basically, both the classic ASP and ASP.Net's session works similarly, they use a session identifier (either stored automatically as a cookie - usually the default, or passed via the URL), and allow you to store key / value pairs of objects against this session identifier.

If you want to share the objects in session, you can either pass the information directly between the two applications when they interact (this would be the "form posting" approach), or store it in an external place, such as the database.  I have some issues with the form posting approach, namely:

- It is passing data which should be strictly on the server to the browser and back again, which has both security and bandwidth implications (you would probably want to at least encrypt the data);
- It assumes that you have a clear handover or boundary between the two applications.  This may or may not be the case.

I don't really see too many benefits to this approach, apart from the fact that it's probably the simplest, as long as you have limited interactions (say, a few fields, and only one or two pages that interact).  The same argument goes for any other approach that passes all of the session info to the browser and back to the server (e.g. storing everything in cookies).

Other approaches will assume that you have a place to store your session, let's assume a database for now.  With a database, we have a single place where the data exists, and each application can simply read and write to this single place.  If you have a large number of different interactions, and / or the systems don't have a clear handover to each other, this is clearly an easier approach.

What remains is a question of how to encode the different types of data and how to store it.  This is essentially a question of encoding, and you would need to be fairly clear on the different data types being used on each side (you should make sure that the ASP.Net code uses types that are at least logically equivalent to the ASP data types).

To go about implementing this, I would create a database implementation which supports how I want to store my session data.  It could be a simple key / value pair table, along with data type information, or it could be more normalised than that, it's your decision.  After this, I would create a new implementation of Session for each application, which makes use of this database.  All that is left is to replace all references to the standard Session objects with the new Session that you've created, and everything should work.  This is probably similar to what you've done, but I am specifically mentioning the use of a database as a data store.

Performance issues and the cleaning of old sessions should be relatively easy to work out, although this implementation will definitely be slower than an in-memory implementation.

Comment: thank you very much for the thorough explanation. I already implemented one of the approach you've mentioned here which is the "Form Posting" as what you called it. The second approach is much simple than the first one. However, the problem of the second approach is, I need to save the sessions (let say I encoded it and place into db using key value pair) for every user into the db, read the data from there when going back and forth from the website1 to the other website. and then later when you log-out you need to delete the data or may be put a flag that the session is not in used.

Comment: Just imagine if I have a 100 users, then how many times the operation will be called the saving, reading and deleting the data.

Comment: If performance is a major issue, I think there are a number of ways you could optimise the reads and the writes.  If you are willing to change the code to trigger a batch update at the end of each page that modifies the session, the many individual writes can be rolled into one (similarly, reads can be batched).  Alternatively, you could write your own data store, which might just have everything in memory, and use named pipes or something for communicating.  If performance is still a major issue, you are probably over-using sessions, in my opinion.

Comment: I used session for a maximum of five variables only which contain a a maximum 50 bytes including the session name. So I think it is not over used. Anyway, thank you for your ideas. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know its not exactly an answer to your question but I have worked on and integrated my self a few .net and classic asp applications, just wanted to give you some comments from my experience:

it can be confusing if its not well documented..
on some of the systems that were not properly documented when we re-deployed we missed out a .net app that handled part of the functionality

the most solid and best to work with (in my experience) were the ones where we picked one application to be the "core" with other parts making calls to this core to get work done.

for example creating .net applications (desktop, web, handheld) that called classic asp web pages that were effectively providing a simple xml web service - seeing as the classic asp apps tended to be the legacy "core" part of the system. (xml web services are fun to write in classic asp - seriously they are fast and easy to code - no type casting issues ;-) )

I don't know what you are doing here specifically but i found that this approach made the structure of the code more intuitive and actually simplified many odd associated issues beyond sessions e.g. on one app had an access DB used as part of it and only having classic asp access it removed concurrency issues.

May not be of any use but its based experience working with around 10 operational management systems that integrated .net and classic asp in various ways.

Comment: note: i have also consumed .net web services from classic asp, it works fine.  But i prefer to have all my real app logic in one place, with other components being alternative front ends.. this seems to cause the least shocks for devs, bugs tend to be in predictable places.  this also stops there being surprises about whats actually doing the work.. if you see .apsx (or no file extension with mvc) you know to look for a .net app but if there is a problem with app logic its where all the app logic is.

Comment: I think this is a good one, it is centralized and can be consumed by any other web apps, but is this will be working if the application are in a different servers?

Comment: Yes, you are just creating a web service to be consumed.. you can add security (e.g. list of approved ip addresses that are allowed to access it or authentication tokens passed through the client) or leave it unprotected. so long as the "new" app can get an http request to the old one you are in business.

Comment: ok, thanks.Can you please post your code here to help others also who needs it.